# JavaScript iframe slideshow page reload and holding a position

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, slideshow

[Here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud58f0fm/)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("greyscale-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "greyscale-off";
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="slides" onclick="plusDivs(1)"> <iframe width="650" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
      <div class="slides" onclick="plusDivs(1)"> <iframe width="650" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iNJdPyoqt8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="demo greyscale-off" style="background: 
        url('https://www.axure.com/c/attachments/forum/7-0-general-
        discussion/3919d1401387174-turn-placeholder-widget-into-image-
        maintain-interactions-screen-shot-2014-05-29-10.46.57-am.png') no-
        repeat; background-position :center; background-size:120%;" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
        <a href="#">
          <div>
            <p>rainy day</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="demo greyscale-off" style="background: url('https://www.axure.com/c/attachments/forum/7-
        0-general-discussion/3919d1401387174-turn-placeholder-widget-into-
        image-maintain-interactions-screen-shot-2014-05-29-10.46.57-am.png') 
        no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: 115%;" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
        <a href="#">
          <div id="slide">
            <p>costa rica</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That is a little slideshow that I created that works fine with img tags, however, when I put iframe links to youtube it also works but when I change to another video(click on another link) it continues to play it in the background.

I want when I click on the next link to reload the page and stay in that position I tried to use **javascript:history.go(0)** in the link tag but it reloads the page and brings me back to the first iframe. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance!